Reasoning about the Collatz conjecture, multiple infinitely growing trees that never overlap?
I have been pondering the Collatz conjecture recently as a mental exercise, and have run into a problem that has to do with proving that an iteratively growing tree of odd positive integers will contain all positive integers at the limit when the number of iterations is increased to infinity.
I don't genuinely believe that I'm getting close to proving anything, but I would like to learn more about the problem, or about constructing mathematical proofs, through some questions. Here is my reasoning so far:
Starting from 1, a tree of odd positive integers can be constructed by applying the inverse of the regular Collatz function when going from odd number to odd number. If any positive odd integer will be added to the tree with a sufficient finite number of iterations, then all positive odd integers have to converge at 1 after a finite number of regular forwards Collatz steps.
The inverse of the Collatz function when going from odd number to odd number is ((2^k)n - 1)/3, where k is a positive integer corresponding with the number of divisions by 2 of a regular forwards Collatz function step, and n is an odd positive integer. The values for k that are valid depend on n. As the result must be an integer, k is valid if and only if (2^k)n−1 ≡ 0 (mod3). For this to be the case (2^k)n ≡ 1 (mod3). For all nodes that were added to the tree in the previous iteration, the valid values for k are found, and the new odd numbers are added to the tree. The valid numbers for k can be found based on n mod 3: (Based on experimentation, might not actually be true.)
Case 1: n ≡ 0 (mod3):
These n can be written as 3 + 6j, where j is a non-negative integer. No integer k is valid, as n multiplied by any integer remains divisible by three. This means that 2kn - 1 is always ≡ 2 (mod3). These have to be leaf nodes in the tree.
As one of these numbers can never lead to any other number on a backwards iteration, no other number can lead to one of these nodes in a forwards iteration.
On a forwards iteration these always lead to a node where n ≡ 1 (mod3)  which are Case 2 nodes.
Case 2: n ≡ 1 (mod3):
These n can be written as 1 + 6j. For k to be valid (2^k)(1 + 6j) ≡ 1 (mod3). For this to be the case, k has to be even. The function creating the next values from n when n ≡ 1 (mod3) can be written as ((2^(2 + 2k))n - 1)/3, or ((2^(2 + 2k))(1 + 6j) - 1)/3
where if k=0 and j=0 the resulting number is ≡ 1 (mod3).
If k+=1 the resulting mod3 is cycled up by 1.
If j+=1 the resulting mod3 is cycled down by 1.
As n is always multiplied by 2 at least twice in this case, the resulting number is always larger than n.
As k can be increased from 0 to infinity, for any n an infinite number of numbers in each case are added to the tree.
Case 3: n ≡ 2 (mod3):
These n can be written as 5 + 6j. For k to be valid (2^k)(5 + 6j) ≡ 1 (mod3). For this to be the case, k has to be odd.
The function creating the next values from n when n ≡ 2 (mod3) can be written as ((2^(1+ 2k))n - 1)/3, or ((2^(1+ 2k))(5 + 6j) - 1)/3
where if k=0 and j=0 the resulting number is ≡ 0 (mod3).
If k+=1 the resulting mod3 is cycled up by 1.
If j+=1 the resulting mod3 is cycled up by 1.
As n is multiplied by 2 only once if k=0, one of the resulting numbers is always smaller than n.
As k can be increased from 0 to infinity, for any n an infinite number of numbers in each case are added to the tree.
Any number that is already in the tree may not be reached again in a later iteration, as that would mean that the number would have multiple forwards connections. This means that at each backwards iteration an infinite number of novel odd numbers are added to the tree.
As I understand it, this would not yet prove that eventually any odd number will be added to the tree. This is because the added numbers might ever increase, leaving some smaller missing numbers. Is this reasoning about the coverage of the tree correct, and can this be mathematically described or proven somehow to either be the case or not? I suspect this to be an extremely challenging problem, but if solved, would this prove or disprove the Collatz conjecture assuming that my intermediate steps are correct and can also be proven?
Additionally I imagine an approach like this could be used to exclude the possibility of divergence or cycles. A divergent path or cycle would have to consist of Case 2 and/or Case 3 nodes, due to Case 1 nodes not having any incoming forwards connections. Through backwards iterations the smallest Case 2 or Case 3 node in the divergent path or the cycle would create an infinite tree as is created originating from 1. Any of these trees could not overlap with the tree originating from 1, as this would mean that at least one single node has multiple forwards connections. Is this approach at all interesting in ruling out the possibility of divergent paths or cycles? Is anyone known to have tried it?
Any good reads on related subjects that you could recommend for a novice?

This must have been tried from others , concerning possible cycles different from $4-2-1$ , it is known that such a cycle must be unimaginably long , so structural proofs that there is no such cycle are almost surely doomed to fail. Even worse is the situation for possibly diverging sequences. If there were one , it is unlikely that we would be able to detect that. How should such a proof look like showing that some sequence diverges ? Noone has the slightest idea.

This is a construction you can perform for any function $f : X \to X$ from a set $X$ to itself called taking the backwards orbit $f^{-\infty}(x)$, also known as the basin of attraction of $x$. Here $X$ is the set of odd natural numbers and you are thinking about the sped-up version of the Collatz function which always divides by an appropriate power of $2$. This means the Collatz conjecture is equivalent to the claim that the backwards orbit $f^{-\infty}(1)$ of $1$ consists of all odd natural numbers.
This construction of the backwards orbit can be used to produce a general structure out of a function $f : X \to X$ which doesn't appear to have a common name but which I call the cycle-tree decomposition; the link describes what this looks like for finite sets and it's a bit more complicated for infinite sets. Here's a nice picture:


As I understand it, this would not yet prove that eventually any odd number will be added to the tree. This is because the added numbers might ever increase, leaving some smaller missing numbers. Is this reasoning about the coverage of the tree correct, and can this be mathematically described or proven somehow to either be the case or not?

Yes, there's no obvious way to tell from here whether any particular odd number shows up. This is just a reformulation of the Collatz conjecture and so it is exactly as difficult as the Collatz conjecture, although it does perhaps help to visualize the difficulty more clearly.

Additionally I imagine an approach like this could be used to exclude the possibility of divergence or cycles.

If there are cycles or divergences then they just don't appear in the backwards orbit $f^{-\infty}(1)$ at all, and again there's no obvious way to tell whether this happens.

Would you chat about this problem?
