Is there a formula to generate all n - step odd numbers that all reduce to 1?
I had a quick question about the Collatz Conjecture. According to the function in which the Collatz Conjecture is defined, all even numbers must necessarily turn into an odd number. Therefore, it seems sufficient to prove the problem only for odd numbers. My question is as follows. Let's look at the steps below.
$$
17\rightarrow 13\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 1
$$
or
$$
3\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 1
$$
As we see, we have "$4-$step" and "$3-$step" chains.
Why don't we come up with a general formula that will create "$4-$step" or "$3-$step" chains (which all go to $1$) and include or generate all such odd numbers? Or does such a formula already exist, but it does not work ?

You can do this by running the Collatz recursion backwards. But it doesn't solve the Collatz problem because it's still not at all clear how to show that every odd number appears in such a chain. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4944228/reasoning-about-the-collatz-conjecture-multiple-infinitely-growing-trees-that-n/4944252#4944252.

@QiaochuYuan Thanks. Can you explain your comment more clearly? A little more, please ?Such a formula does not exist or exist but does not help ?

It exists but it doesn't help.

@QiaochuYuan Wow. Can you share us this $n-$ step formula like $2^n$ here, please ? I am curious!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711060/some-details-about-collatz-conjecture/2712111#2712111

@Collag3n - i've looked at your linked post; just one more aspect: it is correctly mentioned that in the list of exponents $l_k$ the $l_k$ are only allowed with some modular conditions to produce integer values. But I do not see this as a deep problem: once you have produced some fractional value by a wrong $l_k$ then no following combinations of any $l_*$ can produce an integer value. So, assigning "wrong" $l_k$ does not invalidate the attempt to prove the power of this method to generate all odd integers. (it is surely a little detail only, but for me it has some relevance)

@Gottfried Helms , that's a link to a post I wrote long ago (a few months after starting exploring the Collatz conjecture and joining this site). My remark on the parity of the exponents is not fully correct. Since that time, we had a more detailed discussion about it (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4649071/considerations-on-the-sequences-of-the-3n-1-problem/4650720#comment9820319_4650720), but I must admit that I put that conjecture "on hold" a year ago and only posted that link without much thoughts

@Collag3n - concerning your current comment: everything is ok, I've nothing to criticize, as well as nothing in the linked answer. I just wanted to generate attention to the aspect that I wrote about.

Let start with the 2-step chain
You need
$$
3n+1=2^k
$$
i.e. $n=(2^k-1)/3$ for $k$ even
So the $3$ step chain are given by all the $n$ such that
$$
3n+1=2^k \frac{2^{2h}-1}{3}
$$
This equation ha an integer solution iif
$$
2^k (2^{2h}-1) =3 \mod 9
$$
If $h=1 \mod(3)$
$$
2^{2h}-1=3 \mod(9)
$$
and so the result is true for any $k$ even
If $h=2 \mod(3)$
$$
2^{2h}-1=6 \mod(9)
$$
and so the result is true for any $k$ odd.
So the $3$-chains are given by
$$
\begin{align}
n=\dfrac{2^{2k}(2^{2(3h+1)}-1)-3}{9}\\
n= \dfrac{2^{2k+1}(2^{3h+2}-1)-3}{9}
\end{align}
$$
for any $k,h$ positive integer (including $0$)
You can continue to obtain the $4$ chains with the same methods, but the calculation became tedious and as said in the comments does not resolve the conjecture.

Well, of course this doesn't help. But we are looking for direct $n-$ step formula . Like $2^n$ . But, this is trivial.

@user If you want the general $n$-step formula then why did you ask for the formula for $3-$step and $4$-step? Btw  following your notation $2^n$ is a 1-step chain.

There is no problem in your answer. +1 Thank you. I gave an example for $3-$ step formula, just to explain what I am looking for. $2^n$ yes $1$ step. I mean $f(n)$ function.

@user thank you, but you should edit the body of your question to specify that you are looking for a general formula. As it is written it looks like you are trying to obtain only the small chains

The best way to structure this is to count $x\mapsto \frac{3x+1}2$ as one step and $x\mapsto \frac x2$ as one step.  Because then the predecessors of $1$ comprise a complete binary tree and that has precisely $2^n$ children in generation $n$.
But watch out on a couple of counts:
Firstly, because $x=1$ is a solution to $(3x+1)/4=x$ it follows that precisely one quarter of all solutions are duplicates of other solutions.
Secondly, some of these will be ternary fractions and not just odd numbers.
To get the actual numbers generated, you can use the formula given by Lagarias and Bernstein 2019.  To generate all the numbers at $n$ steps away from $1$, start by writing all the binary numbers of length $n+1$ in the form:
$$\sum_{l=0}^n 2^{d_l}$$
Then for each binary number evaluate:
$$2^{n}-\sum_{l=0}^n 3^{-l}2^{d_l}$$.
Those are all the numbers that lead to $1$ in $n$ steps.
Now you only wanted odd numbers - well those are precisely the numbers for which your original binary string was odd, i.e. it ended in a $1$.  That follows from the fact that these two sums are related by an isometric homeomorphism over the 2-adic numbers.  This is another result from the 2019 paper I mentioned above.
Finally, you probably only wanted integers (i.e. excluding the "odd" ternary rationals).  Well the integers are the numbers for which the frequency of ones in your binary strings read from left to right, never step above $\log_3(2)$ of all the digits.  And that's given by Littlewood-Offord theory, which Terrence Tao discusses a little in his 2011 blog on the subject.
You may need to double-check that last number it might be $\log_6(2)$ or something similar.  I haven't time to be precise - but I thought it better to give you a possibly imprecise answer which tells broadly the correct story, than to not answer at all.

Please note I corrected an error in the second sum.
